# Add user to local security policy on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, lsa

When using the code from [LSA Functions Privileges and Impersonation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4863/LSA-Functions-Privileges-and-Impersonation)

on Windows Server 2008R2 it works fine to add a user to the logon as a service policy.
When using this code on Windows Server 2012 it doesn't work. The function 'LsaAddAccountRights' returns an strange number which can't be translated via 'LsaNtStatusToWinError' to a windows error. The return code is something like 1034061105409818720. Every time when I run the same code, it returns a different number.
Can someone provide some help because I'm stuck?

Comment: The initial import statement was:

Answer (score 1):

The initial statement used was:
 _
Private Shared Function LsaAddAccountRights(PolicyHandle As IntPtr, AccountSid As IntPtr, UserRights As LSA_UNICODE_STRING(), CountOfRights As Long) As long
End Function

The solution was changing the result type into UInt32.